# How to convert a SAS (.sas) file to be opened in R?

Tags: r, sas

I received a SAS file (.sas), but I don't have a SAS license, would it be possible to open this file in R using some package in a simple way?

With the `.sas` file open in R I intend to access the database that is associated with it. I could do this using a temporary SAS license, but for me it will be too bureaucratic to do so, and I am more familiar with R which is 100% free.

NOTE: I can't share the file because it's third-party data.

Comment: A `.sas` file is a code file.  It is just a text file. You can open it with R or any other tool that can read text files.

Comment: I didn't understand the reason the question is closed, for lack of details. What details would be needed? if with these few words I summed up my problem. The situation is simple but complex, I have a `.sas` file and I would like to open it in R(Rstudio)

Comment: What is it you want to DO with the SAS code once you open it in R?  Show what you tried. Explain how the result is different than what you wanted to happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In RStudio, in the Files pane navigate to the file you'd like to open.
Click on the file and select `View File` and it will open.

.SAS files are text files that store programs they typically do not create data unless it's a data step that has data.

Comment: I regret that the community closed the question. Anyway, I managed to open the file as you said and access the data. Unfortunately I couldn't do this "translation" from one format to another, but anyway your answer answers the question. Greetings!!

Comment: You can post on communities.sas.com for an answer if you're stuck on understanding what's in the SAS code.